# ReactJS/Javascript: React.createElement expecting string but passed object

Tags: javascript, neo4j, create-react-app, react-apollo, graphql-js

I am having a problem with React when I try to render a graph with my data.  The page is blank but the console give me this error message:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.

I am sending a query to a Neo4j DB with the help of Apollo and graphql and would like to display some of the results. The error above is coming from my Graph component (UserList.js)

**UserList.js**

```
class Graph extends React.Component {

    constructor({data}) {
        //console.log('construc data' ,data);
        const times = d3.extent(data.action.map(action => action.timestamp))
        console.log('construc data' ,times);
        const range = [50, 450]
        super({data})
        this.scale = d3.time.scale().domain(times).range(range)
        this.state = {data, times, range}
        //console.log('state' ,this.data);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let group
        const { target } = this.refs

        const Canvas = ({children}) => 
    <svg height="200" width="500">
        {children}
    </svg>



        group.append('circle')
    .attr('cy', 160)
    .attr('r', 5)
    .style('fill', 'blue')

group.append('text')
    .text(d => d.year + " - " + d.event)
    .style('font-size', 10)
    .attr('y', 115)
    .attr('x', -95)
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)')


    const TimelineDot = ({position, txt}) =>
    <g transform={`translate(${position},0)`}>

        <circle cy={160} 
                r={5} 
                style={{fill: 'blue'}} />

        <text y={115} 
              x={-95} 
              transform="rotate(-45)" 
              style={{fontSize: '10px'}}>{txt}</text>

    </g>
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state
        const { scale } = this
        return (
            <div className="timeline">
                <h1>{this.props.name} Timeline</h1>
                <Canvas>
                    {data.action.map((action, i) => 
                        <TimelineDot position={scale(action.timestamp)} 
                                     txt={`${action.timestamp} - ${action.action}`}
                        />
                    )}
                </Canvas>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, 
    { options: (ownProps) => { 
      console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
      return ({ second: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                              endTime: ownProps.endTime
       } }) 
    } } )(Graph);
```

Comment: I don't think your `TimelineDot` method makes sense. Need to wrap in in parens (it seems to just a have a phantom `}` at the end)

Comment: It closes out the parens here txt={.

Comment: `(<TimelineDot position={scale(action.action.timestamp)} 
                                     txt={`${action.timestamp} - ${action.action}`}
                        />)`

Comment: Still erroring out.

Comment: I read on here that somethings it could be because of import/export statements.  I played around with some but everytime I tried adding {} around any of them the program does not render.

Comment: After some console logging it looks like the map function does not like dealing with the JSON file assigned to data.

Comment: The problem seem to lie here: `{Object.keys(this.state.data.action).map((action, i) => (
                        <TimelineDot position={scale(action.timestamp)} key={i}
                                     txt={`${action.timestamp} - ${action.action}`}  />
                    ))}`

Comment: Can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Comment: I wrapped `this.state.data.action` inside an array and still getting the error. In addition to trying Object.keys. Nothing is working so far.

Comment: Hope someone can help me with this.  Its frustrating to be at the bottom of your code and be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defined `const Canvas =` and `const TimelineDot =` inside `componentDidMount()`, so that's they only place they're known. Try moving defining them into `render()` to use them.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the code in general. I don't see `group` used anywhere, but also it looks to be manipulating the DOM directly instead of letting React handle that (unless I'm misreading).

Answer (score 0):

Function defined in 'options' should return object:

```
return { second: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                   endTime: ownProps.endTime
   } }
```

**with curly brackets interpreted as tag/react component (jsx)** - object is not tag/component then error